# Iterate array of objects without using foreach typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Am working on an a array of object.structure given below.

```
[
    {
        "matListParent": "CH",
        "dParent": "CUST1",
        "isAllSelected": true,
        "childItems": [
            {
                "item": "Display1",
                "isSelected": true
            },
            {
                "item": "Display2",
                "isSelected": false
            }
        ]
    },
  {
        "matListParent": "CH2",
        "dimParent": "CUST2",
        "isAllSelected": true,
        "childItems": [
            {
                "item": "Display5",
                "isSelected": true
            },
            {
                "item": "Display6",
                "isSelected": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Am trying to get **isSelected** true **item** value.i have tried something like this

```
data.filter(
        (matModel: any) => matModel.matListParent === "CH").map(
          (model: any) => model.childItems).map((item: any) => item).filter((list: any) => list.isSelected);
```

It return an empty array.

What was the mistake on the above code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution code

```
data.filter(
        (matModel: any) => matModel.matListParent === "CH").map(
          (model: any) => model.childItems).map((item: any) => item[0]).filter((list: any) => list.isSelected);
```

### Issue explanation

so,

After 1st `filter((matModel: any) => matModel.matListParent === "CH")` and 1st `map((model: any) => model.childItems)`, we are getting an array of array just like below

```
[
  [
    { item: 'Display1', isSelected: true },
    { item: 'Display2', isSelected: false }
  ]
]
```

So when you try to apply a `map((item: any) => item)` to it again it is giving the same result as above. after that your last `filter((list: any) => list.isSelected)` will give you nothing.

The above solution will help you and also there are a lot of ways to solve this problem I hope you know how to overcome this problem because now you know where it is going in the wrong direction

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const data = array
.filter((elem) => elem.matListParent === "CH")
.map(elem => elem.childItems.filter((val) => val.isSelected));
```

result: you get only =

```js
const array = [
  {
    matListParent: "CH",
    dParent: "CUST1",
    isAllSelected: true,
    childItems: [
      {
        item: "Display1",
        isSelected: true
      },
      {
        item: "Display2",
        isSelected: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    matListParent: "CH2",
    dimParent: "CUST2",
    isAllSelected: true,
    childItems: [
      {
        item: "Display5",
        isSelected: true
      },
      {
        item: "Display6",
        isSelected: false
      }
    ]
  }
];

const data = array
  .filter((elem) => elem.matListParent === "CH")
  .map(elem => elem.childItems.filter((val) => val.isSelected)).flat(Infinity);
  
  console.log(data)
```

```
[
  { item: 'Display1', isSelected: true }
]
```